# Finding probability given MGFs

Tags: probability, self-study, moment-generating-function

The question is as follows:

> The MGF of $X$ is given by $M_X(t) = e^{4e^t -4}$ and that of $Y$ is given by $M_Y(t) = (\frac{3e^t+1}{4})^{20}$.
>   Assume also that $X \perp Y$. Compute $P(|XY|\leq 1)$.

My attempt at solving was as follows. I would like to see if my answer is correct or needs revision:

> Clearly, $X\sim Pois(4)$. Notice that 
>   $$\frac{3e^t+1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}e^t + (1-\frac{3}{4})$$
>   $$\implies Y\sim Bin(20,\frac{3}{4})$$
>   We have the probability distributions of our R.Vs now.
>
> Let $Z=XY$. Then we have 
>   $$P(|Z|\leq 1) = P(-1\leq Z\leq 1) = P(Z\leq 1) - P(Z \leq -1) = P(Z \leq 1)$$
>   where $P(Z\leq -1) = 0$ since $X,Y\geq 0$ integer-wise.
>
> Denote $p(X,Y)$ to be the joint mass function of $X$ and $Y$. It follows that
>   $$P(Z\leq 1) = p(0,0) + p(0,1) + p(1,0) + p(1,1)$$
>   $$ = (\frac{1}{4})^{20} + 20\frac{3}{4}(\frac{1}{4})^{19} + 4e^{-4}(\frac{1}{4})^{20} + 20\cdot 4e^{-4}\frac{3}{4}(\frac{1}{4})^{19}$$
>   by independence ($X\perp Y$).

Again, I'm posting this to see if my logic is sound or if my logic went awry anywhere. If there are any holes, if one could point me in the proper direction I would be much obliged!

Comment: You've left out the $n \choose x$  part of the binomial distribution in your last line.  I would have simplified your argument (very) slightly by noting that since $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative, $|XY| = XY$ and skipped the "$-1$" parts.  Otherwise, looks good!

Comment: Oh very good notice~~ I thought I included that in the answer. LOL it's on paper just not on screen. Thank you!

Comment: Please add the `self-study`tag.

Comment: The event $Z\le 1$ is the disjoint union of the events of the form $(X,Y)=(x,0)$ for $x\ne 0$, $(X,Y)=(0,y)$ for $y\ne 0$, $(X,Y)=(0,0)$, and $(X,Y)=(1,1)$.  You seem to have used "$=$" rather than "$\ne$" in the first two.